# Preventing Database Locking during updates

Tags: mysql, database

I am pulling a large amount of data (700k lines) from one database (**Source Database**), performing some data manipulation, then inserting/updating another database (**Lookup Database**) with the altered data.

The lookup database is being accessed by users regularly throughout the day.  They are only performing select statements.  The updates to the lookup database occur hourly.  As the size of the data in the source database increases, I'm noticing much higher numbers of "lock wait timeout exceeded" errors when updating the lookup database.  Is my assumption correct that this is most likely resulting from the select statements and update statements accessing the same data?  That would make sense as the larger number of updates occurring would more frequently hit data that is being accessed by the users.

In my attempts to fix the situation I've increased the lock wait timeout to 120 (up from 60) but that has had very little effect.

One thought I had was to update into a new table in the lookup database, then swap (in the software the users are using) the database their queries go to.  Any other ideas how I might resolve the issue?

I'm not sure if it's relevant but I'm using MySQL and the two databases are on completely separate servers.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of storage engine you are using ?

Comment: what is the size of database ?

Comment: are you able to make a copy of look up database which is busy ?

Comment: Nope, I get another "lock wait timeout exceeded" message

Comment: If you are able to make copy of db, it will take 1-2 minute for copy of database. if yes then post my view